# Map over result of right-hand side in for comprehension before assigning to value

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I love Scala's for comprehensions! I would love them even more if I could find a way to map over the right-hand side result before assigning it to a value. Say I have the following code:

```
case class Person(name: String)
def getPersonById(id: Long): Future[Option[Person]] = ???

case class Dog(color: String)
def getDogById(id: Long): Future[Dog] = ???

def addStringToFile(name: Seq[String]): Future[Unit] = ???
val id: Long = ???

for {
  person <- getPersonById(id)
  name = person.map(_.name)

  dog <- getDogById(id)
  color = dog.color

  _ <- addNamesToFile(Seq(name, color).flatten)
} yield name
```

I don't actually need `person` or `dog` as an intermediate value; the are only valuable to the extent that I can extract a property from them on the very next line. Ideally what I'd like to do would look something vaguely like this:

```
for {
  name <- getPersonById(id))>>.map(_.name)
  color <- getDogById(id))>>.color
  _ <- addNamesToFile(Seq(name, color).flatten)
} yield name
```

But obviously this isn't valid Scala. Outside of a for-comprenshion I would do:

```
val name = getPersonById(id).map(_.map(_.name))
val color = getDogById(id).map(_.color)
```

But the neat thing about the for-comprehension is that I don't need to explicitly perform the outer `.map`, and the "Future" part is hidden away.

Is it possible to map over the result of a right-hand side expression in a for-comprehension *before* assigning it to a value?

Comment: Your original code snippet doesn't compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/o5aGfLZxQouCfGUzThZWhw

Comment: I don't see much reason to bother about the `person` variable in your first example. On the contrary it make things clearer than a bunch of `_`.

Comment: Yeah the code snippet was meant to be illustrative rather than intended to be compiled and run, but I've updated it to compile. And it is true this trivial example doesn't make it abundantly clear how intermediate values can be a waste of space, but I am opting for succinctness and readability in the question.

Comment: If you are using `cats`, you could use `OptionT`. In that case, you will have to change the signature of `addNameToFile`.

Comment: Yes, cats' monad transformers like `OptionT` help with the specific example as written above (and we use `OptionT` and `EitherT` often), but the example above is intended to demonstrate how – sometimes – I'd like to map over the result _after_ the for-comprehension unwraps the outside monad. `OptionT` solves that in the above example, but not in the general case. I'll add a general case to the question to make this more clear.

Comment: So, the question is "can I map over something without calling it `map`", right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally what I'd like to do would look something vaguely like this:
>
> ```
> for {
>   name <- getPersonById(id))>>.map(_.name)
>   color <- getDogById(id))>>.color
>   _ <- addNamesToFile(Seq(name, color).flatten)
> } yield
> ```

Note that you can actually write *exactly that* by simply replacing your cryptic `)>>.` with `map` :)

```
  for {
     name <- getPersonBy(id).map(_.map(_.name))
     color <- getDogById(id).map(_.color)
     _ <- addNamesToFile(name.toSeq :+ color)
  } yield name
```

The only difference between this and what you wrote is `.map` vs. `>>`
If you like your syntax more for some reason, make an implicit:

```
object FunnySyntax { 
    implicit class FS[T](val f: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
       def >>[P] (m: T => P): Future[P] = f.map(m)
     }
}
```

Now, you can do

```
name <- getPersonById(id) >> { _.map(_.name) }
color <- getDogById(id) >> { _.color }
```

This is almost *exactly* what you had - just a couple of braces and an underscore added ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `person` you can replace

```
for {
  person <- getPersonById(id)
  name   =  person.map(_.name)
  _      <- addNameToFile(name)
} yield name
```

with

```
for {
  name <- getPersonById(id).map(_.map(_.name))
  _    <- addNameToFile(name)
} yield name
```

partially using your another approach

> Outside of a for-comprenshion I would do:
>
> ```
> getPersonById(id).map(_.map(_.name))
> ```

---

> The point of using a for-comprehension is to eliminate just such boilerplate as `.map(_.map` in the first place!

Sounds like you want monad transformers

```
import cats.data.OptionT

for {
  person <- OptionT(getPersonById(id))
  name   =  person.name
  _      <- OptionT.liftF(addNameToFile1(name))
} yield name

def addNameToFile1(name: String): Future[Unit] = ???
// def addNameToFile1(name: String): Future[Unit] = addNameToFile(Some(name))
```

(@JohnyTKoshy advices the same in the comments).

Or without `person`

```
for {
  name <- OptionT(getPersonById(id)).map(_.name)
  _    <- OptionT.liftF(addNameToFile1(name))
} yield name
```

---

Your new code

```
for {
  person <- getPersonById(id)
  name   =  person.map(_.name)

  dog    <- getDogById(id)
  color  =  dog.color

  _      <- addStringToFile(Seq(name, Some(color)).flatten)
} yield name
```

can be re-written without `person` and `dog` as

```
for {
  name  <- getPersonById(id).map(_.map(_.name))
  color <- getDogById(id).map(_.color)
  _     <- addStringToFile(Seq(name, Some(color)).flatten)
} yield name
```

or with monad transformers as

```
for {
  name  <- OptionT(getPersonById(id)).map(_.name)
  color <- OptionT.liftF(getDogById(id)).map(_.color)
  _     <- OptionT.liftF(addStringToFile(Seq(name, color)))
} yield name
```

> Ideally what I'd like to do would look something vaguely like this:
>
> ```
> for {
>   name  <- getPersonById(id))>>.map(_.name)
>   color <- getDogById(id))>>.color
>   _     <- addNamesToFile(Seq(name, color).flatten)
> } yield name
> ```

Inventing new syntax instead of `.map(_.name)`, `.map(_.color)` is an overkill.

Comment: Quoting myself from the question: 'But the neat thing about the for-comprehension is that I don't need to explicitly perform the doubly-nested map, and the "Future" part is hidden away.' The point of using a for-comprehension is to eliminate just such boilerplate as `.map(_.map` in the first place!